# Large prime number

Tags: python

Instructions
Compute the prime factors of a given natural number.

A prime number is only evenly divisible by itself and 1.

Note that 1 is not a prime number.

Example What are the prime factors of 60?

Our first divisor is 2. 2 goes into 60, leaving 30. 2 goes into 30, leaving 15. 2 doesn't go cleanly into 15. So let's move on to our next divisor, 3. 3 goes cleanly into 15, leaving 5. 3 does not go cleanly into 5. The next possible factor is 4. 4 does not go cleanly into 5. The next possible factor is 5. 5 does go cleanly into 5. We're left only with 1, so now, we're done. Our successful divisors in that computation represent the list of prime factors of 60: 2, 2, 3, and 5.

You can check this yourself:

2 * 2 * 3 * 5 = 4 * 15 = 60 Success!

My code:

```
def factors(value):
    y = []
    x = [i for i in range(2,value+1) if value%i ==0]
    print(x)
    while value !=1:
        for i in x:
            while value%i==0:
                y.append(i)
                value = value/i
  
    return y
```

It passes all tests but one . value = 93819012551. The program just freezes. What should I do with big numbers so it doesn't freeze? Thank you

Comment: It's not freezing; it's just taking a very long time to determine all the factors of such a large number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stop checking factors once you reach the square root of the remaining number. At that point the remaining number is guaranteed to be a prime number (or 1).  Also, you should use integer divisions (`//`) to reduce the value.

For example:

```
def factors(value):
    f,inc  = 2,1   # factor, increment (skips multiples of 2 & 3)
    result = []
    while f*f<=value:                     # up to √remaining
        while value%f == 0:               # add divisors
            result.append(f)
            value //= f                   # reduce target value
        f,inc = f+inc,2 if f<5 else 6-inc # next factor (2,3,5,7,11,...)
    if value>1: result.append(value)      # remainder is prime if >1
    return result

print(factors(93819012551)) # [11, 9539, 894119]
```

Comment: `//` is cleaner, but since we've already verified that `factor` does indeed divide `value`, `/` is always going to return a floating-point equivalent of an integer.

Comment: If you don't mind, can you  please tell me how the & works here?

Comment: @raduc: It is just a trick to allows to process 2 and then only odd numbers. If `factor` is 2, you get 3, but if `factor` is odd, you will get `factor + 2`.

Comment: Probably cleaner to just handle 2 as a special case at the beginning; then you can simply iterate over `range(3, sqrt(value) + 2, 2)` without any arithmetic tricks on every iteration.